# Wordpress output message

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

[I want the text before the button, does anyone one how?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8ryS.jpg)

[heres the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nhk4C.jpg)

function wc_add_to_cart_message( $product_id ) {
    $titles = array();

```
if ( is_array( $product_id ) ) {
    foreach ( $product_id as $id ) {
        $titles[] = get_the_title( $id );
    }
} else {
    $titles[] = get_the_title( $product_id );
}

$titles     = array_filter( $titles );
$added_text = sprintf( _n ( '%s has been added to your cart.', '%s have been added to your cart.', sizeof( $titles ), 'woocommerce' ), wc_format_list_of_items( $titles ) );

// Output success messages
if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) ) {
    $return_to = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect', wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : home_url() );
    $message   = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url( $return_to ), esc_html__( 'Continue Shopping', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) );
} else {

    $message   = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a>%s', esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' ) ), esc_html__( 'View Cart', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) );
}

wc_add_notice( apply_filters( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', $message, $product_id ) );
```

}

QUESTION #2

function wc_add_to_cart_message( $product_id ) {
    $titles = array();

```
if ( is_array( $product_id ) ) {
    foreach ( $product_id as $id ) {
        $titles[] = get_the_title( $id );
    }
} else {
    $titles[] = get_the_title( $product_id );
}

$titles     = array_filter( $titles );
$added_text = sprintf( _n( '**DIV HERE** %s has been added to your cart.', '**DIV HERE** %s have been added to your cart.', sizeof( $titles ), 'woocommerce' ), wc_format_list_of_items( $titles ) );


// Output success messages
if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) ) {
    $return_to = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect', wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : home_url() );
    $message   = sprintf( '%s <a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> ', esc_html( $added_text ), esc_url( $return_to ), esc_html__( 'Continue Shopping', 'woocommerce' ) );
} else {
    $message   = sprintf( '%s <a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a>', esc_html( $added_text ), esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' ) ), esc_html__( 'View Cart', 'woocommerce' ) );
}

wc_add_notice( apply_filters( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', $message, $product_id ) );
```

}

Comment: Please add code as formatted plain text.

Comment: Code as a JPEG is not very helpful...

Comment: my bad... edited now :)

Comment: Do you mean the text "<< Test >>...." should show before the button Vis handlekurv?

Comment: yeah :) tried to change places in the $added_text with no luck..

Comment: Isn't is simply a matter of placing the %s before the <a href and moving the $added_text to be the first param to sprintf?
Or am I missing something?

Comment: I see now - that was the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Try this

```
// Output success messages
if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) ) {
    $return_to = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect', wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : home_url() );
    $message   = sprintf( '%s <a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> ', esc_html( $added_text ), esc_url( $return_to ), esc_html__( 'Continue Shopping', 'woocommerce' ) );
} else {
    $message   = sprintf( '%s <a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a>', esc_html( $added_text ), esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' ) ), esc_html__( 'View Cart', 'woocommerce' ) );
}

wc_add_notice( apply_filters( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', $message, $product_id ) );
```

Question #2 Answer

```
    // Output success messages
if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) ) {
    $return_to = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect', wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : home_url() );
    $message   = sprintf( '<div class="acmsg">%s</div> <a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> ', esc_html( $added_text ), esc_url( $return_to ), esc_html__( 'Continue Shopping', 'woocommerce' ) );
} else {
    $message   = sprintf( '<div class="acmsg">%s</div> <a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a>', esc_html( $added_text ), esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' ) ), esc_html__( 'View Cart', 'woocommerce' ) );
}

wc_add_notice( apply_filters( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', $message, $product_id ) );
```

Comment: thanks alot! did the trick :)

Comment: Can someone also help me with the following question? I wanna put a div tag around the "%s has been added to your cart." so I can edit it in css. Tried to put it just around the text, but the output was ofcourse plain text :P

Comment: Can you please post the updated code and expected output?

Comment: edit over with "question #2" hope its understandable :)

Comment: let me know if the updated answer for Question #2 worked?

Comment: watch out, were handling a genious here!!!! worked out great! thanks again :)

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked out :)